# how to check if 3 characters are in consecutive alpha order

Tags: python, sequence, alphabetical

Just curious, what's the most pythonic/efficient way to determine if
sequence of 3 characters are in consecutive alpha order?

Below a quick&dirty way that seems to work, other, nicer implementations?

I suppose one alternative approach might be to sort a copy the
sequence and compare it with the original. Nope, that wouldn't account
for gaps in the sequence.

(This is not homework - listeners to NPR Sunday Morning progam will
know)

```
def checkSequence(n1, n2, n3):
    """ check for consecutive sequence of 3 """
    s = ord('a')
    e = ord('z')

#   print n1, n2, n3
    for i in range(s, e+1):
        if ((n1+1) == n2) and ((n2+1) == n3):
           return True

    return False


def compareSlice(letters):
    """ grab 3 letters and sent for comparison """

    letters = letters.lower()
    if checkSequence(ord(letters[0]), ord(letters[1]), ord(letters[2])):
        print '==> seq: %s' % letters
        return True

    return False
```

Comment: Is this the [reason](http://www.npr.org/2012/04/08/150202658/a-mix-up-at-the-music-fest)?

Comment: It seems like the next step is a dictionary to check against. Try [this](http://thedatahub.org/dataset/wiktionary/resource/8147edd1-6932-4816-aa88-2fa4fdc60ab5).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easy:

```
>>> letters = "Cde"
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> letters.lower() in ascii_lowercase
True
>>> letters = "Abg"
>>> letters.lower() in ascii_lowercase
False
```

Alternatively, one could use `string.find()`.

```
>>> letters = "lmn"
>>> ascii_lowercase.find(letters) != -1
True
```

I guess a function using this would look like:

```
def checkSequence(*letters):
    return ''.join(letters).lower() in ascii_lowercase
```

Comment: This seems to me the most forward and simple solution, very nice.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a nice pythonic way to check that for arbitrarily long sequences of chars:

```
def consecutive_chars(l):
    return all(ord(l[i+1])-ord(l[i]) == 1 for i in range(len(l)-1))
```

Comment: Edited to remove the square brackets to make `all` iterate over a generator, instead of creating the entire list of `True`s and `False`s first.

Comment: neat .. for some reason I had not come across the built-in all() function before

Answer (score 4):

```
ord('a') < ord(a)+1 == ord(b) == ord(c)-1 < ord('z')
```

Comment: +1 Very interesting! And the only answer here that is correct. All others miss the alphabetic check.

Comment: @MarkByers Yes it is =) , although here solution space is limited and direct search is easier

Answer (score 4):

This could be simply done as

```
>>> x=['a','b','c']
>>> y=['a','c','b']
>>> z=['c','b','a']
>>> x==sorted(x) or x == sorted(x,reverse=True)
True
>>> y==sorted(x) or y == sorted(y,reverse=True)
False
>>> z==sorted(x) or z == sorted(z,reverse=True)
True
>>>
```

Think it this way. Letters are consecutive iff they are sorted either ascending or descending.

As pointed out in the comment as this will not work if the sequence contains holes, another approach would be

```
>>> ''.join(x).lower() in string.lowercase
True
>>>
```

Comment: This approach was already mentioned in the question and, as the OP points out, it doesn't work.

Comment: @MarkByers: I have updated my answer with another possible solution

Comment: Still is wrong though. `ace` gives `True`. And you should use `//` not `/`. Without that change your code will give an error in Python 3.

Comment: OK +1 for the effort, though I still think half your answer is wrong.

Comment: +1 for the second solution, which seems good and clean. You should probably move it to the top of the answer rather than leaving an incorrect one first.

Comment: Your second solution seems equivalent to Joel Cornett first approach (or his function at the bottom) - thanks. Might be helpful for others to just delete the first incorrect suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
l = letters.lower()
if len(l)>=3 and ord(l[0])+2==ord(l[1])+1==ord(l[2]): print "yes"
else: print "no"
```